# Pass bundle from one tab fragment to another tab fragment

Tags: android

Creating app in which i want to pass bundle data from one tab fragment to another.I have created two tab and getting list in one fragment but now i want to select item from `Recyclerview` list using `checkbox` and set this selected item to another tab fragment on swipe.Using `viewpager` for creating tab.In second tab fragment set bundle and in first tab fragment  get bundle but not working.

In second fragment i set bundle

```
    Bundle data = new Bundle();
    data.putString("name",contactArrayList.get(position).getContactName());
    data.putString("mobile",contactArrayList.get(position).getContactNumber());
    Fragment fragment = FragmentInfo.newInstance(1);
    fragment.setArguments(data);
```

In first fragment i get bundle

```
if (bundle != null) {
       String name = bundle.getString("name");
       String mobile = bundle.getString("mobile");
        // object of Model Class
        mydata.setName(name);
        mydata.setMobile(mobile);
        myDataArrayList.add(mydata);

    }
```

Comment: in which method you are getting bundle values in next fragment?

Comment: in onCreateView..

Comment: onCreateView only call once in viewpager, when you first time add and show fragmetns.

Comment: public static FragmentInfo newInstance(int columnCount) {
        return new FragmentInfo();}    if i am calling here in fragment so it's making method non static and if i make this non static,my viewpager adapter showing error.

Comment: you need to implement an interface first, so you could know which fragment is currently showing on the screen because both are in onResume stat.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

create a mechanism to access the tag across `fragments` via the main activity, . - Call `getTag()` in `onCreateView()` of `FragmentB`. Then pass it to the main activity. When `FragmentA` need to pass something to `FragmentB`, it retrieve it from `MainActivity`.

```
 public static class TabsAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter
  implements ActionBar.TabListener, ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {

  private final Context mContext;
        private final ActionBar mActionBar;
        private final ViewPager mViewPager;
        private final ArrayList<TabInfo> mTabs = new ArrayList<TabInfo>();

        static final class TabInfo {
            private final Class<?> clss;
            private final Bundle args;

            TabInfo(Class<?> _class, Bundle _args) {
                clss = _class;
                args = _args;
            }
        }

  public TabsAdapter(FragmentActivity activity, ViewPager pager) {
   super(activity.getSupportFragmentManager());
            mContext = activity;
            mActionBar = activity.getActionBar();
            mViewPager = pager;
            mViewPager.setAdapter(this);
            mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
        }

  public void addTab(ActionBar.Tab tab, Class<?> clss, Bundle args) {
            TabInfo info = new TabInfo(clss, args);
            tab.setTag(info);
            tab.setTabListener(this);
            mTabs.add(info);
            mActionBar.addTab(tab);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

  @Override
  public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  }

  @Override
  public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  }

  @Override
  public void onPageSelected(int position) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   mActionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
  }

  @Override
  public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  }

  @Override
  public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
   Object tag = tab.getTag();
            for (int i=0; i<mTabs.size(); i++) {
                if (mTabs.get(i) == tag) {
                    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(i);
                }
            }
  }

  @Override
  public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  }

  @Override
  public Fragment getItem(int position) {
   TabInfo info = mTabs.get(position);
            return Fragment.instantiate(mContext, info.clss.getName(), info.args);
  }

  @Override
  public int getCount() {
   return mTabs.size();
  }

 }
```

For full implementation see this link:

http://android-er.blogspot.com/2012/06/communication-between-fragments-in.html